# Openlayers Modify interaction only works for a short time on mobile device

Tags: javascript, openlayers

See the official example here, open with a mobile device: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html?q=edit and try to edit a polygon.

After you drag the vertice of the polygon for a short while, the interaction stopped responding. You can still drag it again or drag other parts.

Is this a bug of openlayers? Any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out its an issue of Openlayers itself. See: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/10910

The solution solves this problem as well, use @ol/dev or add a `touch-action: none` to the map div.